# Translation from Domain model to view model is slow when a data source is azure db (free version)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I have a domain class Case which has multiple dependent tables

```
public class Case
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseUser> CaseUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CasePoaSerie> CasePoaSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pod> Pods { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Poa> Poas { get; set; }

    public Case()
    {
        CaseUsers = new Collection<CaseUser>();
        Sectors = new Collection<Sector>();
        CasePoaSeries = new Collection<CasePoaSerie>();
        Pods = new Collection<Pod>();
        Poas = new Collection<Poa>();
    }
}
```

Consider this table has 3 rows of data and my repository method return's all these 3 rows with values of all other dependent tables (CaseUsers, Sectors, CasePoaSeries, Pods, Poas). I translate this domain model to a view model in my service client class.

My Translator Code

```
public static class CaseTranslator
{
    public static Case UpdateToDomain(Models.Case modalcase)
    {
        var domaincase = new Case()
        {
            CaseId = modalcase.CaseId,
            EndDateTime = modalcase.EndDateTime,
            Name = modalcase.Name,
            StartDateTime = modalcase.StartDateTime,
        };

        modalcase.CaseUsers.ForEach(x => domaincase.CaseUsers.Add(CaseUserTranslator.UpdateToDomain(x)));
        modalcase.CasePoaSeries.ForEach(x => domaincase.CasePoaSeries.Add(CasePoaSeriesTranslator.UpdateToDomain(x)));
        modalcase.Sectors.ForEach(x => domaincase.Sectors.Add(SectorTranslator.UpdateToDomain(x)));
        modalcase.Poas.ForEach(x => domaincase.Poas.Add(PoasTranslator.UpdateToDomain(x)));

        return domaincase;
    }

    public static Models.Case UpdateToModel(Case domaincase)
    {
        if (domaincase == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var modalcase = new Models.Case()
        {
            CaseId = domaincase.CaseId,
            EndDateTime = domaincase.EndDateTime,
            Name = domaincase.Name,
            StartDateTime = domaincase.StartDateTime,
        };


        domaincase.CaseUsers.ForEach(x=> modalcase.CaseUsers.Add(CaseUserTranslator.UpdateToModel(x)));
        domaincase.Poas.ForEach(x => modalcase.Poas.Add(PoasTranslator.UpdateToModel(x)));
        domaincase.Pods.ForEach(x => modalcase.Pods.Add(PodsTranslator.UpdateToModel(x)));
        domaincase.CasePoaSeries.ForEach(x => modalcase.CasePoaSeries.Add(CasePoaSeriesTranslator.UpdateToModel(x)));
        domaincase.Sectors.ForEach(x => modalcase.Sectors.Add(SectorTranslator.UpdateToModel(x)));
        return modalcase;
    }
}
```

Each translator follows the same pattern.

My ServiceClient code

```
public List<Case> GetCasesByUserId(int userId)
    {
        var activeCases = new List<Case>();
        var cases = _caseRepository.GetActiveCasesForUser(userId);
        cases.ForEach(o=> activeCases.Add(CaseTranslator.UpdateToModel(o)));
        return activeCases;
    }
```

**My Problem**
When I am using LocalDb as my data source my method is very fast, see the below screenshots.

Data from localdb takes approx. 124 ms. to retrieve data.
[localdb data retrieval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9UZg.png)

My system takes approx. 392 ms. to translate these data.
[localdb data translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKZ2Y.png)

Now if I change my data source to an azure db it takes approx. 1,069 ms. to retrieve data from db.

[azuredb data retrieval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJgW.png)

My system takes approx. 2,62,604 ms. to translate these data which are retrieved from azuredb.
[azuredb data translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmAw6.png)

We can clearly see that the translator takes more time (simply unacceptable delay) to process the same amount of data which is translated very fast if its from localdb.

I am confused now as I don't know what is the real problem.

***Is something wrong with my translator code or Is it the azure db which is responsible for this delay?***

Addition info I am using entity framework code first approach with Manuel migrations. The azure db that I use is a free plan.

Azure plan
We are using shared plane, the web site is running in an azure server which is free plan and the application data base is running in an azure server with standard plan.

Comment: Do you need all the case related data all at once ? or can you fetch only whatever tables as and when required ?

Comment: I don't need all the case related data during this operation, but in a different scenario, I need all data. My doubt is even with all the data when I run it local it takes ms. to complete the task, but if I run it with azure db it takes more than 30 sec. for the same amount of data.

Comment: It's not at all clear from your code what's going on or what the issue is.  Please isolate the code that actually queries the database and populates entities.  I might guess that you're currently using Lazy Loading, which results in lots of separate queries.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This is what my repository method does 
DbSet.Where(x => x.CaseUsers.Any(o => o.UserId == userId)).Where(m => m.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now && (m.EndDateTime == null || m.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now)).ToList();  When i upgraded the azure plan, the site became fast. But if you have any suggestion to improve the current code it's always welcomed.

Comment: That looks like you are using Lazy Loading to populate your entity graphs.  It might be faster to use .Include() or to turn off Lazy Loading craft a couple of separate queries to load parts of your entity graph, and let the Change Tracker fix-up the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, there is no problem with the code, all the problem was due to the hosting of the website.

As I mentioned when we hosted the site in Azure free plan, the site is very slow compared with localhost. As we upgraded the plan of the hosting site, the site became fast.

Conclusion: If you host your web client in the Azure free plan, you will have a performance drop. Upgrading the azure plan to higher version will help you to achieve the real speed of the site.